# Default implicit object/definition for a typeclass

Tags: scala, typeclass

I have a requirement to intercept toString of DateTime, LocalDate and Option in the runTime.

```
@implicitNotFound("No member of type class ReportString in scope for ${T}")
trait ReportStringTransformer[T] {
  def toReportString(e: T): String
}

object ReportStringTransformer {
  implicit object ReportStringTransformerDateTime
    extends ReportStringTransformer[DateTime] {
      override def toReportString(e: DateTime): String =
        ISODateTimeFormat.dateTime().print(e)
    }

  implicit object ReportStringTransformerDate
    extends ReportStringTransformer[LocalDate] {
      override def toReportString(e: LocalDate): String =
        ISODateTimeFormat.date().print(e)
    }

  implicit def ReportStringTransformerOpt[T]: ReportStringTransformer[Option[T]] =
    new ReportStringTransformer[Option[T]] {
      override def toReportString(e: Option[T]): String = e match {
        case Some(obj) => ReportStringTransform.transform(obj)
        case None => ""
      }
    }
}

object ReportStringTransform {
  def transform[T](obj: T)(implicit t: ReportStringTransformer[T]): String =
    t.toReportString(obj)
}
```

I could add a default transformer for Any class at the end which could only 
be picked up after these, but is there any other cleaner way to do?

Answer (score 2):

Your implementation could be simplified as follows:

```
@implicitNotFound("No member of type class Show in scope for ${T}")
case class Show[T](f: T => String) extends AnyVal

object Show {
  implicit val showDateTime = Show[DateTime](ISODateTimeFormat.dateTime() print _)
  implicit val showDate = Show[LocalDate](ISODateTimeFormat.date() print _)
  implicit def showOpt[T](implicit s: Show[T]) = Show[Option[T]](_.fold("")(s.f))
}
```

To have a fallback for anything that is not a `DateTime`, a `LocalDate` or an `Option` of either the these, you could the following trait as a paraent of `object Show`

```
trait LowPriorityShow {
  implicit def showAnything[T] = Show[T](_.toString)
}

object Show extends LowPriorityShow { ... }
```

Comment: Since 2.10, local implicits and implicits inherited fall into the same scope. The above wouldnt work

Comment: Also are you using cats?

Comment: Not using cats in this example, show is the standard name for this type class. Your statement about implicit scope is incorrect, see http://eed3si9n.com/revisiting-implicits-without-import-tax.

Comment: Thanks for the link, but Im still facing some issues -
https://gist.github.com/tejancsu/f89cc5b70093a9dd518faedac67e450b

date implicit is picked up as expected but option implicit is not being picked up as expected. Please take a look at the gist abv ^^

Comment: Please minimize it and open another question that precisely explain what you've tried, what you expect, what you don't understand.

Answer (score 1):

Probably late to the party, but your issue on your gist [here](https://gist.github.com/tejancsu/f89cc5b70093a9dd518faedac67e450b), is that the implicit resolution picks up the type Some[String] for the second case you put. other than that, the solution given by OlivierBlanvillain is great and it should solve your needs.

You can verify that this is your case by casting to Option[String]

```
println(MyShow.show(Some("abc"): Option[String])) // this will work as you expected
```

playing with variance/covariance you can make it work as expected [link](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/variances.html).

```
import org.joda.time.{DateTime, DateTimeZone}
import org.joda.time.format.ISODateTimeFormat

trait Show[-T] {
  def show: T => String
}

trait LowPriorityShow {
  implicit def showAnything[T] = new Show[T] {
    def show: T => String = _.toString
  }
}

object Show extends LowPriorityShow {

  implicit val showString: Show[String] = new Show[String] {
    def show: String => String = identity
  }

  implicit val showDateTime: Show[DateTime] =
    new Show[DateTime] {
      def show: DateTime => String =
        ISODateTimeFormat.dateTime().withZone(DateTimeZone.forID("America/New_York")).print
    }

  implicit def showOpt[T : Show]: Show[Option[T]] =
    new Show[Option[T]] {
      def show: Option[T] => String = _.fold("")(implicitly[Show[T]].show)
    }

  def show[T : Show](v: T): String = implicitly[Show[T]].show(v)
}

println(Show.show(DateTime.now()))
println(Show.show(Some("abc")))
println(Show.show(12))
```